# How to configure and test external JS requests now that Rails 5.1 deprecates `xhr` and `xml_http_request`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am testing a controller action that responds to a script that can be embedded on external sites.

```
xhr :get, :index, params: { format: :js }
```

Rails has started raising the following note

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: `xhr` and `xml_http_request` are deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1.
Switch to e.g. `post :create, params: { comment: { body: 'Honey bunny' } }, xhr: true`.
```

If I modify the controller spec as per these suggestions

```
get :index, params: { format: :js }, xhr: true
```

I get the following error

```
ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest:
        Security warning: an embedded <script> tag on another site requested protected JavaScript. If you know what you're doing, go ahead and disable forgery protection on this action to permit cross-origin JavaScript embedding.
```

This same error led to me using `xhr :get` in the first place, as per [Rail 4.1 upgrade notes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#csrf-protection-from-remote-script-tags). I am now questioning my assumptions about what is happening here, and whether I do indeed "know what I'm doing"!

Is the correct way to resolve this error in this context to explicitly disable the Rails CSRF token for this action? i.e.,

```
# my_embeddable_controller.rb
protect_from_forgery except: :index
```

And if so, what was the previous `xhr :get` syntax doing that enabled requests to avoid cross-origin errors?